# Splitting at html tag in regex

Tags: php, regex, split

I have a string as such:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
Mauris non rutrum velit. Morbi sed turpis in urna fermentum sodales.<br>
Proin aliquet nisi a congue egestas.
</p>
```

I'm trying to write a program in PHP to take each word and put it in a MySQL database. I think the easiest way to do this is to use regex and put each word (and the punctuation AND space after it, but NOT the linebreak tag, which should be a separate word).

The current regular expression I am using is:`/([\S]{1,} ?)/`. This expression has the following issues:

1. **FIXED** Grabs each word and punctuation, but not the whitespace. When I try to include the whitespace, then all of the words become one match.
2. Grabs the [br] as part of a word. I need the [br] to be a separate word, with the word before it NOT having whitespace after it (e.x. line 1: {adipiscing }{elit.},{[br]}

It is fine that the paragraph tags are grabbed, That is part of the functionality I need for my MySQL table.

Comment: Maybe this regex: `<?(?!\b(p>))[\w.,]+\s*>?`

Comment: Did any of the answers here work for you; or are you having issues with any of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a regex. Use strip tags to remove all elements because `<sup><sub><em><i><strong><b><s>` and other formatting elements will all break. Then just explode on spaces.

```
$string = '<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
Mauris non rutrum velit. Morbi sed turpis in urna fermentum sodales.<br>
Proin aliquet nisi a congue egestas.
</p>';
$words = explode(' ', trim(strip_tags($string)));
foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo $word . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet,
consectetur
adipiscing
elit.
Mauris
non
rutrum
velit.
Morbi
sed
turpis
in
urna
fermentum
sodales.
Proin
aliquet
nisi
a
congue
egestas.
```

You could use a regex rather than the explode if you want to strip off the punctuation but it sounded like you wanted that with the word.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just just words but HTML tags & spaces;

1- Strip all HTML tags
2- Use a RE pattern that doesn't put the white spaces

This is what I understood from the question :), but sorry if I'am wrong.

```
$input = strip_tags($input);
$words = preg_split('~\s+~', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Remove the modifiers, they are useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
(<\s*[^\s="'>]+(\s+[^\s="'>]+(=("[^"]*"|'[^']*'))?)*\s*/?>|<\s*/\s*[^\s="'>]+\s*>|\S+)\s*
```

This regex has three parts:

`<\s*[^\s="'>]+(\s+[^\s="'>]+(=("[^"]*"|'[^']*'))?)*\s*/?>` This finds HTML opening tags. It allows for arbitrary padding with white-space in the tag, for quoted attributes, for Boolean attributes, and for self-closing tags.

`<\s*/\s*[^\s="'>]+\s*>` This finds HTML ending tags. It's simpler since it doesn't need to do attributes.

`\S+` This is the one that just looks for a sequence of non-white-space characters, and catches the non-HTML words and punctuation.

Finally, I've grouped the whole thing and added `\s*` to catch any white-space after either a tag or word.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: it's because you haven't set the good delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- Ignore whitespace:

> `var str = '<p> some string here... </p>   ';`

```
var res = str.split(' ');
```

- Replace `<br>` with ''.

So, the result should be: `var res = str.split(' ').replace('<br>', '');`